# Simple python app deployed but not deployed

Tags: dokku

I just installed dokku for the first time and I'm struggling with an apparently very simple problem... I made a sample python app that just logs an env variable:

```
import os
import time

API_TOKEN = os.getenv('API_TOKEN')

while True:
    print(f'API_TOKEN is {API_TOKEN}')
    time.sleep(1)
    pass
```

With a Procfile as this:

```
worker: python temp.py
```

The deploy looks normal and successful, however if I try to look at the logs, dokku says

```
App <app name> has not been deployed .
```

Am I missing something very trivial?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By default dokku only scales up the web process if it is present. Any workers or other processes are scaled to 0 otherwise known as "App < app name > has not been deployed"

To deploy your app you need to log onto the box and scale up the worker by running:

`dokku ps:scale <app name> worker=1`

change 1 to a larger number if you want more workers

If you often deploy the app to different dokku instances and have to search for this solution over and over again you can instead create a file in the root of your app called `DOKKU_SCALE`. In it you can set the default scale of all the proceses, like so:

```
worker=1
```

That reminds me, I need to go do that now. It is driving me nuts.

Comment: Wow thank you Derek! My worker process wasn't starting on Dokku, I was completely lost and didn't understand why it wasn't working!
By curiosity, do you know where in the docs this is explained? I tried to search but didn't find anything relevant

Comment: Part of it is there, but it doesn't mention worker: https://dokku.com/docs/processes/process-management/#the-web-process